# "got" in "You've got to be kidding me!"

Tags: verbs, idioms

What's the meaning of got in "**You've got to be kidding me!**"?
I already knew that "**have got**" and "**have**" can be used interchangeably in some cases. But I'm not sure about this one.

I even saw "**You got to be kidding me!**".

Comment: According to http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/got, both *got* and *have got* are used for saying "have" in informal speech.

Comment: In this context, you can change "have got to" to "must" ⇒ _You must be kidding me!_

Comment: That's what I asked under the following answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no different from the common use of "have got" versus "have".

Even "got" is used quite commonly:

> Got a moment?
>   You've got a moment?
>   You have a moment?

Are all commonly used, albeit by different people in different situations.

The same goes for

> You got to be kidding me!
>   You've got to be kidding me!
>   You have to be kidding me!

Comment: Thanks. This "have to", is it the one [used to express certainty, necessity, and obligation](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/haveto.html)?

Comment: All three versions express a certainty in this case: _I am quite sure that you are kidding me_.